# Piping data of QIODevice

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have one `QIODevice` which receives data from an undefined source.
What i want to do is Dump all data to a file being sent from `QIODevice`, but if i read then another handler which depends on original data changes.

Basically what i want is

```
void piping( QIODevice* Data )
{
    if ( outgoingData )
    {
        qDebug()<<Data->readAll();
    }

    // gets nothing as readAll has already consumed all data 
    dependentOn(Data);
}
```

function `dependentOn` is not defined by me, so i cannot change its definition.

Comment: You might try saving the position, reading, then seeking back to the saved position.  Really depends on the type of device it is.  You might rethink your design to read the data and pass the byte array to anyone that is interested in it.

Comment: Yea, But the problem is in handling a sequential device eg: socket, i cannot even emulate it, `dependentOn` is not defined by me so i cannot change its definition.

Comment: [QBuffer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html) might work.

Comment: Hmm..Seems it will work, but what about other device operations, like if Device is Closed then ?

Answer (score 2):

`qint64 QIODevice::peek(char * data, qint64 maxSize)` is what you want.

From the documentation :

> qint64 QIODevice::peek(char * data, qint64 maxSize)
>
> Reads at most maxSize bytes from the device into data, without side
>   effects (i.e., if you call read() after peek(), you will get the same
>   data). Returns the number of bytes read. If an error occurs, such as
>   when attempting to peek a device opened in WriteOnly mode, this
>   function returns -1.

Reference : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#peek

Comment: Does peek has another internal pointer ? i.e. peek(data,100) will return first 100 bytes and then peek(data,100) will return next ?

Comment: I ran a test, it doesn't has an internal pointer, so i cannot read bytes by bytes, i have to create a 100000 byte buffer, which is waste of mem.

Comment: So you want to say that overloaded function won't be allocating extra memory even if i set max size to 10000000 ?